# How to add/edit/remove items in Quick Switch Scheme in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I can access Quick Switch Schema in Intellij Idea using `` ctrl + ` `` shortcut. This provides a very fast way of accessing some common menus. I was wondering if there is a way to customise this list.

Comment: Yes, by plugins

Comment: Well, i was looking for a builtin option. That said, can you please provide the name of the plugin that could help us do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to modify the `Quick Switch Scheme` action using the UI. But you can create your own [`Quick Lists`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2022.2/customize-actions-menus-and-toolbars.html#configure_quick_lists), which are very similar. You can create them in `Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Quick Lists`, add any action you want to a list and assign a keyboard shortcut.